# RTTI. Как обратить к статическому полю класса, имея объект Class для него?

Tags: java, рефлексия, rtti

Имеем класс `Allocator`, который имеет метод `allocate(Class)`. Как без знания того,
объект `Class` какого класса пришёл, вытащить из него поле с возможностью его изменить?

Вариант с использованием `objOFclassClass.newInstance()` не подойдёт. Охота без лишних затрат памяти на создание объекта обойтись.

```
class X {
    public static boolean f = false;
}

class Y {
    public static boolean f = false;
}

class Z {
    public static boolean f = false;
}

class Allocator {
    public static void allocate (Class c) throws Exception{
        // Предполагая, что (c.name == "X" или "Y" или "Z"), как сделать что то в духе:
        // c.setStaticField("f",true);  ???
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- С помощью метода [`getDeclaredField`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredField-java.lang.String-) получаем объект класса [`Field`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html)
- Изменяем поле с помощью вызова метода [`set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#set-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-) у этого объекта

```
Field field = c.getDeclaredField("имя_поля");
field.set(null, true /* новое значение */);
```

[Код на Ideone](https://ideone.com/VGmpBR)